# Non-official Cisco VPN client for Linux

Tags: linux, vpn, cisco

Does anyone know of a good VPN client that is not the official one from Cisco for Linux?

Comment: Sounds like a question you should ask your Cisco account rep.

Comment: yes - but I dont have Cisco account or any connection to cisco -:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used [vpnc](http://www.vpnc.org/) in the past with great success. It also integrates into Network manager very nicely - at least under Ubuntu

Comment: Works like a charm in Fedora and Mac also.  Vpnc can also import all the gateway settings from a PCF file.  The only thing I have found is that If you have an encrypted group password in the PCF, it cannot deal with that portion you would have to get that from your network admin.

Comment: @Alex: vpnc package ships /usr/bin/cisco-decrypt, a tool that will decrypt the group password (enc_GroupPwd in the .PCF file) :-)

Comment: @Fran Cool.  I knew it was trivial to decrypt, didn't know there was a utility that did it :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The shrew soft client also works quite well. http://www.shrew.net/software

Answer (score 1):

For future references. I ended up using [OpenConnect](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect.html) with [vpnc](http://www.vpnc.org) scripts. We connect to our VPN using a web-login with a OTP (One Time Password) (retarded I know), simply using vpnc was not enough, however one can use it's configuration files in combination with OpenConnect, which in turn worked great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Open Source Client vpnc. It's a RPM Package. I used this Client for many years on my Debian. Today most people use Cisco Anyconnect for VPN Dialin because the VPN Client is going End-of-Life by July,24 2014.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/security/vpn-client/end_of_life_c51-680819.html

Answer (score 0):

Here are some good resources where you can download cisco vpn client for linux:

[cisco vpn](http://projects.tuxx-home.at/ciscovpn/clients/linux/)

We've been using them without no problem in Fedora 13 and kernel 2.6.x.

[how-to](http://projects.tuxx-home.at/?id=cisco_vpn_client)

But be careful because as the other mate said, cisco is dropping cisco-vpn-client.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the openconnect cisco vpn client.

http://www.humans-enabled.com/2011/06/how-to-connect-ubuntu-linux-to-cisco.html